# Can F# modules be monkey-patched?

Tags: f#, module, extension-methods, monkeypatching

Quick question. I just read that if you wanted to add a function to e.g. the List module, you can define a new List module with that function:

```
module List
  let foo = // ...
```

Does this have the effect of adding `foo` to the main List module, or do you have to explicitly open the new `List`? The former seems like Ruby's "monkey patching"; I guess the latter would be more like extension methods.

(I'd try this out but I'm not near a compiler.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a lot like namespaces; they're "open".  That is, I may have two files or two assemblies that contribute types into a namespace, and then if I use those files or reference those assemblies and say

```
open ThatNamespace
```

I see the union of all the members.

Answer (score 3):

This works in a fashion similar to extension methods:

```
module List =
    let doSomething lst v = lst |> List.nth v
```